# How to correctly implement in AngularJs: Custom directive reuse several times in single page

Tags: angularjs, directive

I created a custom directive that has event handler on it and use it 3 times.

```
<div sl-entity-browser btn_label="Browse supplier" handler="supplier_selection_handler(entity)" />

<div sl-entity-browser btn_label="Browse checker" handler="checker_selection_handler(entity)" />

<div sl-entity-browser btn_label="Browse approving officer" handler="approvar_selection_handler(entity)" />
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.supplier_selection_handler = function(entity){
  $scope.selectedSupplier = entity;
}

$scope.checker_selection_handler = function(entity){
  $scope.selectedChecker = entity;
}

$scope.approvar_selection_handler = function(entity){
  $scope.selectedApprovingOfficer = entity;
}
```

My directive:

```
return {
            scope : {
                btnLabel : '@',
                handler: '&'
            },
            restrict: 'AE',
            templateUrl: '/common/sl-entity-browser',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) { 

                // expose selected account to the outside world
                scope.selectEntity = function(entity) {
                    return $timeout(function() {
                        return scope.handler({
                            entity: entity
                        });
                    });
                }

            }
        };
```

HTML template:

```
<button title="browse account"  class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#slEntityModal"> {{ btnLabel }}</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="slEntityModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="width: 90%">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Browse entities</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-group pull-right" style="width: 300px">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="query" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="row-top-buffer" style="margin-top: 15px"/>
                            <div class='row' style="border-top: 1px solid #dcdcdc; padding-top: 10px">
                                <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1"><span style="font-weight: bold; padding-left: 2px;">Acct No</span></div>
                                <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5"><span style="font-weight: bold; padding-left: 30px;">Name</span></div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6"><span style="font-weight: bold">Address</span></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row-top-buffer" style="margin-top: 5px"/>
                            <div class="row" style='max-height: 500px; overflow: auto;'>
                                <div ng-show="!slEntities">Loading entities...</div>
                                <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr data-dismiss="modal" ng-repeat="entity in entities = (slEntities | filter:query)" style="cursor: pointer" ng-click="selectEntity(entity)">
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">{{entity.accountNo}}</td>
                                        <td style="width: 480px;">{{entity.name}} <span class="label {{entityClass(entity.marker)}} pull-right">{{convert(entity.marker)}}</span></td>
                                        <td>{{entity.address}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr ng-show="entities.length == 0"><td colspan="3" align="center">No records found</td></tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The directive will render a button that will display a modal when clicked. The modal contains a table of items. If a certain item is selected, the modal will be disposed and the event should trigger the correct one as defined. The problem is that the first directive instance' event handler (supplier_selection_handler) is always called.

I am new to AngularsJs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share html template of this directive..

Comment: @entre Pls take a look at my template

Comment: When I tried not use a modal the events responded accordingly.

Comment: you can use $timeout.. to throttle the clicks, so that only the last one opens within a given time period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the modal opened by your directives (all of them!) is the first directive's modal. Notice that all your modals share the same ID? and the `data-target` of your buttons share the same ID? Since an ID of an element is unique, then once an element with that specific ID is found, it'll stop searching for another element with such ID. Thus, all your buttons that opens a modal simply opens the first modal.

I recommend that you use [**angular-bootstrap's modal**](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) instead, the component itself runs in the AngularJS context so no scoping problems may occur.

The example below shows how to create a directive that can makes use of angular-bootstrap's modal, I trimmed down the code below to simplify the demo.

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/iHJxY7oMTVY37bfYPeU8?p=preview)

**INDEX**

```
  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">

    <button sl-entity-browser 
            btn-label="hello world" 
            handler="messageHandler('This is a message from hello world')"
            class="btn btn-primary">
      Hello World?
    </button>

    <button sl-entity-browser 
            btn-label="Yeah Baby" 
            handler="messageHandler('WEEEE wOoOoOw')"
            class="btn btn-primary">
      Baby?
    </button>

    <button sl-entity-browser 
            btn-label="Boom!"
            handler="messageHandler('This is kaboom boom!')"
            class="btn btn-primary">Kaboom!</button>

  </body>
```

**MODAL**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    {{ btnLabel }}
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button 
      ng-click="handler()"
      class="btn btn-primary pull-left">
      Click ME!
    </button>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
(function(angular) {

  var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

  app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $window) {

    // handler function
    $scope.messageHandler = function(message) {
      $window.alert(message);
    };

  });

  // directive assignment
  app.directive('slEntityBrowser', slEntityBrowser);

  function slEntityBrowser() {
    // directive definition
    return {
      scope: {
        btnLabel: '@',
        handler: '&'
      },
      controller: slEntityBrowserController,
      link: slEntityBrowserLink
    };
  }

  // directive controller
  function slEntityBrowserController($scope, $modal) {

    // create open() method
    // to open a modal
    $scope.open = function() {
      $modal.open({
        scope: $scope,
        templateUrl: 'sl-entity-browser-modal.html'
      });
    };

  }

  // directive link
  function slEntityBrowserLink(scope, elem) {
    // register click handler on the current element
    // to open the modal
    elem.on('click', function() {
      scope.open();
    });
  }

})(window.angular);
```